# Efficient grouping of rows from Nx2 integer numpy array to match sequential elements in rows

Tags: python, numpy

Allright, got a strange one for the numpy speed-freaks out there.

I have data such that:

- Nx2 array of integer values
- Each integer between 0 and N-1 appears twice
- There will be one or more 'loops' through the data.

A 'loop' would be a subset of the rows ordered such that each row shares a single element with the row above it and the other element with the row below it. Goal is to find arrays of indices to the data that yield the closed loops.

Example data (single loop):

```
In: data = np.array([[0, 7],
                     [1, 8],
                     [2, 9],
                     [3, 0],
                     [4, 1],
                     [5, 2],
                     [6, 3],
                     [4, 7],
                     [8, 5],
                     [9, 6]])
```

Example solution:

```
In: ordered_indices = np.array([0, 7, 4, 1, 8, 5, 2, 9, 6, 3])

In: data[ordered_indices]
Out: array([[0, 7],
            [4, 7],
            [4, 1],
            [1, 8],
            [8, 5],
            [5, 2],
            [2, 9],
            [9, 6],
            [6, 3],
            [3, 0]])
```

There is no guarantee of the order of elements in the row; i.e., 7 could be the first element in both rows it appears in, or the first in one and the second in the other.

The data is on the order of N=1000; solutions with loops are too slow.

For convience, typical data can be generated with the script below. Here, the indices of the ordered data follow a periodic pattern, but that wouldn't be true in the actual data.

Generate sample data:

```
import numpy as np
import sys

# parameters
N = 1000
M = 600

# initialize array
data = np.empty((N,2), dtype=np.int)

# populate first column
data[:,0] = np.arange(N)

# populate second column by shifting first column; create two loops within the data
inds1 = np.arange(0,M)[np.arange(-7,M-7)]
inds2 = np.arange(M,N)[np.arange(-9,N-M-9)]
data[:M,1] = data[inds1,0]
data[M:,1] = data[inds2,0]

# shuffle order of two entries in rows
map(np.random.shuffle, data)
```

I've written a method that gets the proper results, but it's pretty slow (around 0.5 seconds on my ageing laptop):

Baseline solution:

```
def groupRows(rows):

    # create a list of indices
    ungrouped_rows = range(len(rows))

    # initialize list of lists of indices
    grouped_rows = []

    # loop until there are no ungrouped rows
    while 0 < len(ungrouped_rows):

        # remove a row from the beginning of the list
        row_index = ungrouped_rows.pop(0)

        # start a new list of rows
        grouped_rows.append([row_index])

        # get the element at the start of the loop
        stop_at = data[grouped_rows[-1][0],0]

        # search target
        look_for = data[grouped_rows[-1][0],1]

        # continue until loop is closed
        closed = False

        while not closed:

            # for every row left in the ungrouped list
            for i, row_index in enumerate(ungrouped_rows):

                # get two elements in the row being checked
                b1,b2 = data[row_index]

                # if row contains the current search target
                if look_for in (b1,b2):

                    # add it to the current group
                    grouped_rows[-1].append(ungrouped_rows.pop(i))

                    # update search target
                    if look_for == b1:
                        look_for = b2
                    elif look_for == b2:
                        look_for = b1

                    # exit the loop through the ungrouped rows
                    break

            # check if the loop is closed
            if look_for == stop_at:
                closed = True

    return map(np.array, grouped_rows)
```

So my approach works, but with lists and two nested loops; there must be a slicker way to to do this using numpy's more efficient methods. Any ideas?

Comment: check my answer, is that what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to find a longest "closed loop", than I think you problem is NP-complete (finding a longest simple cycle in an undirected graph).

if you want to find an arbitrary cycle, try depth first search - it's about 0.02s for 1000 elements:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def ordered(data, N):
    edges = defaultdict()
    for v1, v2 in data:
        edges.setdefault(v1, []).append(v2)
        edges.setdefault(v2, []).append(v1)

    visited = [False] * N
    path = None
    for v in range(N):
        if not visited[v]:
            path = dfs(edges, visited, v)
            if path is not None: break
    if path is not None:
        return [[path[i], path[i + 1]] for i in range(len(path) - 1)]


def dfs(edges, visited, v1, vp=None):
    path = [v1]
    if visited[v1]: return path
    visited[v1] = True
    for v2 in edges[v1]:
        if v2 == vp: continue
        path_child = dfs(edges, visited, v2, v1)
        if path_child is not None: return path + path_child
    return None

data = [[0, 7], [1, 8], [2, 9], [3, 0], [4, 1], [5, 2], [6, 3], [4, 7], [8, 5], [9, 6]]
N = 10
ord = ordered(data, N)

[[0, 7], [7, 4], [4, 1], [1, 8], [8, 5], [5, 2], [2, 9], [9, 6], [6, 3], [3, 0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is begging for the scipy.sparse.csgraph module:

```
data = np.random.permutation(data)

import scipy.sparse    
def find_closed_loops(data):
    incidence = scipy.sparse.csr_matrix((np.ones(data.size), (data.flatten(), np.arange(data.size)//2)))
    adjecency = incidence.T * incidence
    n, labels = scipy.sparse.csgraph.connected_components(adjecency, return_labels=True)
    for l in range(n):
        yield np.flatnonzero(labels == l)

for idx in find_closed_loops(data):
    print(idx)
```